# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu - showing under photo in body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the JB DropDown Menu for Bootstrap module in Joomla.

I have the dropdown menu working however, when there is a photo. The menu shows under the image. ie.) blocking the Dropdown Menu. This currently happens in Chrome and Safari.

**Update One-**
No relative or z-index on article/photo css

**Section for Dropdown on left**

```
#_break ul{
  z-index:1000;
}
```

---------- End Update One -----

**(Old Code)**
**Section for photo on right**

```
body.menu-events-and-activities article.post-45{
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

**Section for Dropdown on left**

```
#_break ul{

  z-index:1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Change the z-index for the menu to be higher than the photo. Please include relevant code in your question.

Comment: Sometimes it's `z-index`, sometimes it's not so obvious. You may need to take the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) into account.

Comment: Hey @Aibrean & Jeremy - I've added code of using z-index.

Comment: You have to have positioning set for z-index to work. You don't need z-index on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try something higher to z-index like 1000.

Please try to add z-index to prior div than ul or the li to see if it get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why the heck do your articles have a z-index? They shouldn't.